# How to find a line that's the intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem below:

Determine an equation in parameter form for the intersection line $L$ between the planes

$
x + 2y − z = 0 \quad\mbox{and}\quad 2x + y + z = 0.$

I only have these to equations for the lines how can I find the line $L$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection between two three-dimensional planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395187/intersection-between-two-three-dimensional-planes)

Comment: This question has a poor title. The line you're looking for a way to express doesn't (just) intersect the two planes, in lies in both of them.

Comment: Try to eliminate $z$ so you have an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ on the intersection.  Then substitute this in to either (or both) of the plane equations to get $z$ in terms of $x$ on the intersection

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here is a complete solution:$\,$

[image]

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but as a photo of handwriting it is not useful here.  Try presenting it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site)

Comment: In mathematics educators section of stackexchange a picture is displayed, here no. Here one has to click on it. Could someone please change this software feature?

Comment: I have made it display, but using a picture is undesirable when it could be typed in as mathematical expressions and read more easily by humans and computers.  The feature of making it harder for new users to display pictures is deliberate, so as to discourage this style of answer

Comment: In my solution I have a vector (1,-1,-1) which is nicer than the vector in the solution above, i.e. (3,-3,-3). To me, 3 is too big number for this situation..

Answer (score 2):

May be not the best solution but this is what I would do:
Both planes are defined by normal vectors

$$v = (1, 2, -1)$$
$$w = (2, 1, 1)$$

Doing the **cross product** between these vector would give you another vector which geometrically is the director vector of the intersection line:

$$det\begin{bmatrix}i & j & k \\ 1&2&-1\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix} = 3i -3j -3k$$

[image: Cross product result in green]

And since the planes intersects the origin (0, 0, 0), the line must intersect it too, so the parametric form of the line would just be

$$x = 3t$$
$$y = -3t$$
$$z = -3t$$

[image]